# Sitecore Stimulsoft web report designer Developed Reports Does not Render

Tags: sitecore, stimulsoft

I am developing some reports in Sitecore using stimulsoft web report designer. In that I need to access data in Sitecore master database. I created a sql data connection for the master database and created a datasource as well. When I try to view my blank report using engagement analytics it gives an exception like this

```
Report /sitecore/shell/Applications/Analytics/Reports/Scam/ScamReport.mrt cannot be rendered : System.Exception: c:\Windows\Temp\jp1ck2g2.0.cs(319,64) : error CS1026: ) expectedc:\Windows\Temp\jp1ck2g2.0.cs(319,74) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Windows\Temp\jp1ck2g2.0.cs(319,84) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Windows\Temp\jp1ck2g2.0.cs(319,84) : error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'c:\Windows\Temp\jp1ck2g2.0.cs(319,141) : error CS1026: ) expectedc:\Windows\Temp\jp1ck2g2.0.cs(319,150) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Windows\Temp\jp1ck2g2.0.cs(319,160) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Windows\Temp\jp1ck2g2.0.cs(319,176) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Windows\Temp\jp1ck2g2.0.cs(319,176) : error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Compile(String path, Stream stream, StiOutputType outputType, Boolean autoCreate, Object standaloneReportType)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Compile(String path, Stream stream, StiOutputType outputType, Boolean autoCreate)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Compile(String path, StiOutputType outputType, Boolean autoCreate)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reports.ReportFactory.CompileReport(StiReport report, String reportId)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reports.ReportFactory.FillReport(StiReport report, Database database, ID reportItemId, Nullable`1 startDate, Nullable`1 endDate, String email, IEnumerable`1 filters)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.ReportRunner.ReportPage.FillReport(StiReport report, IEnumerable`1 filterSelection)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.ReportRunner.ReportPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

Does anyone have an idea about this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been quite a while ago since I worked with the Stimulsoft web report designer, but I noticed one thing in your exception: `"Invalid expression term ')'"`

It seems like your expression is not correct, you either have one ')' too much or at an invalid position.

Comment: Hi Martijn, Thanks for your quick reply. But I am not using any expressions other than sql query. The sql query does not have any errors. So I think it's related to some other thing.

Comment: Yes Martijn, it turns out you were correct. The issue was with my sql query. Even thought it executed in SQL Management studio, the report query had issues with it. I checked with a simpler query and it worked.